# Unable to impersonate user in an elapsed Timer event

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer, impersonation

Within a windows service I am facing an issue with impersonating a user.
The impersonation finds place in a System.Timers.Timer Elapsed event.
The timer ticks every 3 seconds. When the imersonation fails and I get "Unable to impersonate user" I do a retry by restarting the timer and it continues and impersonation goes on.

After 3 to 4 days of running this service the impersonation fails again and a retry doesn't work and the application is stuck within the elapsed event.

Is it possible that the Timer ran out of threads?(Threadpool)

How can I prevent a failed impersonation or how do I handle this?

Impersonation code :

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(
    String lpszUsername,
    String lpszDomain,
    String lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    private static IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle,
        int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand that it
    // runs with FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string password)
    {
        //try
        {
            // Use the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
            // the specified user, domain, and password.
            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            // Passing this parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
            tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            // ---- Step - 1
            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName,domainName,password,LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,ref tokenHandle);

            // tokenHandle - new security token
            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }
            // ---- Step - 2
            WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
            // ---- Step - 3
            impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
        }
    }
    // Stops impersonation
    public void Undo()
    {
        impersonatedUser.Undo();
        // Free the tokens.
        if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    }
```

Timer code:

```
 void polling_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StopPolling();

            //doing some stuff some impersonation

            StartPolling();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retries++;
            if (retries < 10)
            {
                StartPolling();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you present the code that you use for the timer and the impersonation? Also specify which timer. Why do you impersonate every 3 seconds?

Comment: Do you have an idea on what the I could do to properly handle this?

Comment: Why do you need to impersonate every 3 seconds? Do you impersonate as the same user every 3 seconds?

Comment: Yes the windows service needs to run under local but the polling needs to access another resource which requires another user and the polling needs to be every 3 seconds.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your approach, but impersonating every 3 seconds feels excessive to me. Why can't you just use a dedicated thread which stays in the impersonated context and polls the resource every 3 seconds, instead of switching every 3 second. This should surely alleviate your situation.

Comment: You have a point there. There was a reason why it wasn't possible but the code has changed a lot and one starts to exclude options. Looking at the code now it might be a solution.